# Passing Data (e.g. sportsbook API) into Bootstrap Modal on Click

Tags: jquery, api, modal-dialog

Beginner developer. I am working on a MLB sports data / sports line web app. I am working through the design right now. Question is that is it possible to pass in API data (e.g. BetData API) to a modal on click (jQuery).

Please let me know if I should clarify.

Comment: yes it is possbile. it would be a great. if you share your code over there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible just create a modal like shown below

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" id="PreviewModal"role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="PreviewTitle">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="PreviewBody">
                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                    
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then have a btn that links to a js function and in the function have something to get the data from your API like

```
$.ajax{
 url : THE URL FOR YOUR API,
 success : function(data){
  $("#PreviewBody").html(JSON.stringify(data))
}
}
```

then once you have validated the data i.e made sure its all correct and matches what you require just use jquery to insert the data into your modal like

the button can be as simple as

```
<button onclick="JSFunc()">Press Me</button>


function JSFunc(){
  $('#PreviewModal').modal('show');
}
```

The modal wont show until the `modal('show')` command is called and dosen't have to be hidden by defualt

Comment: thanks for you comment. I am will be making the ajax call first, and filtering data to an array of objects that lives in the global scope.

Thus, my example would be a bit more complex. Would you suggest dynamically building out the modal within the ajax call, once the data has been retrieved and filtered.

Comment: Modals unlike regular html dont appear when the html is loaded like the rest it will be ignored and wont be displayed until ```$('#PreviewModal').modal('show');``` is called so you can still make your ajax request and then pass the informatiuon into the modal then when you are ready to display the modal just run ```$('#PreviewModal').modal('show');``` and it will be displayed. so the example I include above will still work,